# Spyder - stop consoles accidentally closing

Tags: python, spyder

When I use Spyder, I have fairly frequently accidentally closed the wrong consoles. Usually by a cmd+W. Most applications ask if I want to save before close/confirm I definitely want to close. Spyder just closes, so I may lose training that's been occurring for an hour, say, by a single click or keyboard typo, and I cannot find a way to get it to ask before it does close a console.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: This tool could help: https://sourceforge.net/projects/console/

Comment: probably if you ask this question on stackoverflow you will get an answer in 2 minuts